# Proving $\mathfrak p \mathcal O \neq \mathcal O$ ($\mathcal O$ being the integral closure of a dedekind domain)

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

In Algebraic Number Theory, on page 45, Neukirch proves that $\mathfrak p \mathcal O \neq \mathcal O$, where $\mathfrak p$ is a prime of dedekind domain $\mathcal o$, $K$ is $\mathcal o$'s fraction field, $L$ a finite extension and $\mathcal O$ the integral closure of $\mathcal o$ in $L$. I follow the individual steps but don't really understand what is really going on / what the key idea of the proof is. I also don't understand why the following more natural-seeming and shorter argument wouldn't work:

Suppose $\mathfrak p \mathcal O = \mathcal O$. Then $1 = b x$ for some $b \in \mathfrak p \backslash \{ 0 \}$, $x \in \mathcal O$. But then $x = 1/b \in K$ so $x \in K \cap \mathcal O = \mathcal o$, and then $1 \in \mathfrak p$, a contradiction.

Any enlightenment much appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $\mathfrak{p}$ is principal? In general $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}=\mathcal{O}$ implies only that $1=\sum_{i=1}^k b_ix_i$ for some $b_1,\ldots,b_k\in\mathfrak{p}$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_k\in\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you! That was silly of me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works more general. Let $f: \mathcal o \to \mathcal O$ the ring homomorphism. If $\mathfrak p \mathcal O = \mathcal O$ then $\mathfrak p =f^{-1}(\mathfrak p \mathcal O)=f^{-1}(\mathcal O)=\mathcal 0$. But $\mathfrak p$ was a prime of $\mathcal 0$ and thus $\mathfrak p \neq \mathcal 0$

Comment: It's worth noting that this uses the fact that $\mathcal{o}\subset\mathcal{O}$ is an integral extension. If you try the same for $\Bbb{Z}\subset\Bbb{Q}$, for example, you will fail.

Comment: Ah okay, so I take it it being an integral extension gives me that $\mathfrak p = \mathfrak p \mathcal O \cap \mathcal o$? (Or in the above notation $\mathfrak p = f^{-1}(\mathfrak p \mathcal O)$.) I'll think about that..

Comment: morally that's the going-up property: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element#Integral_extensions